# Using Django F expression with Case, When expression

Tags: django, django-models, orm

I have a Django model like

```
# app/models.py

class tbl_invoice(models.Model):
    invoice_id                      = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    client_id                       = models.ForeignKey(tbl_customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    invoice_number                  = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    date                            = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    amount                          = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    paid_amount                     = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    balance                         = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    date_of_payment                 = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    status                          = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='', blank=True, null=True)
```

I have another view in which I am saving payment record, I want to update `status` as **Paid** or **Unpaid** depending on if the difference between the user-entered amount and `balance` is `0` or not

currently, this is what I have done

```
#app/views.py

if form.is_valid():
    post = form.save(commit=False)
      # rest of the logic goes here
    post.save()
 # this data is saved in another model, after that I update invoice model

tbl_invoice.objects.filter(invoice_id=someIdHere).update(paid_amount=F('paid_amount')+post.amount, 
      date_of_payment=post.date, balance=F('balance')-post.amount, 
      status=Case(
      When(balance=F('balance')-post.amount==0, then=Value("Paid")), 
      When(balance=F('balance')-post.amount!=0, then=Value("Unpaid")), 
   ))
```

this query is updating `status` as blank.

however, using only the `F` expression to update `amount` and `balance` is working fine

```
tbl_invoice.objects.filter(invoice_id=someIdHere).update(paid_amount=F('paid_amount')+post.amount, 
      date_of_payment=post.date, balance=F('balance')-post.amount
```

the above statement is working fine

surely I am making some obvious mistake that I can't figure out.
How can I use the `F` expression with `Case`??

Comment: You're using `When()` wrongly. You just need to use the field name without `F()` inside of when. Change to `balance=0` and make a default value for non 0 value. Try reading https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#when

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, please read [When document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#when) that corresponding to your Django version.
Can check this code below as solution:

```
tbl_invoice.objects.filter(invoice_id=someIdHere).update(paid_amount=F('paid_amount') + post.amount,
                                                     date_of_payment=post.date,
                                                     balance=F('balance') - post.amount,
                                                     status=Case(
                                                         When(balance=post.amount, then=Value("Paid")),
                                                         default=Value("Unpaid")
                                                     ))
```

Comment: this worked!!! Thank you, I would have upvoted this answer if I had enough repo. :D

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, we need to put everything other than the field to the right side of '='

```
status=Case(
    When(balance=post.amount, then=Value("Paid")),
    default=Value("Unpaid")),
)
```

You can also do

```
status=Case(
    When(balance__gt=post.amount, then=Value("Paid")), 
    When(balance__lte=post.amount, then=Value("Unpaid")), 
)
```